# Python concatenate

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I have some Python code like this:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir="D:\\robot\\in",outfile="D:\\robot  \\out\\Concatenated.csv"):
os.chdir(indir)
fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
dfList=[]
colnames=["Data","Price"]
for filename in fileList:
    print(filename)
    df=pandas.read_csv(filename,header=None)
    dfList.append(df)
concatDf=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=0)
concatDf.columns=colnames
concatDf.to_csv(outfile,index=None)
```

It works with some data, but when I run it for another `CSV` files, I have this error:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values
>   have 2 elements

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Are columns in every csv file the same?

Comment: It seems that you're trying to concatenate a dataframe with 2 columns to a dataframe with 4. Make sure all your csv files have the same number of columns

Comment: Please don't post answers as comments.  It bypasses quality control measures, and deprives you of sweet sweet answer points.